# jquery-ui broken

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

scripts that i created two months ago all at once didn´t work.
I have tried restore backup files, but no changes.
This problem appears on all websites, that use scripts from google apis
Functions, that i use are .button() .corner()

Links and scripts:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>       
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.corner.js"></script>
```

Errors:

> BlockquoteUncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert '$("#BuyCredit")' to object
>
> Error thrown at line 3, column 6 in () in http://www.t-samp.net/credit-shop.php:
>   $("#BuyCredit").button().click(function() {
>       called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 2, column 29359 in (b, f) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js:
>           if(c[m].apply(b,f)===!1&&a.stopOnFalse)
>       called from line 2, column 30902 in (b, c) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js:
>           d&&(j?a.once||d.push([b,c]):(!a.once||!e)&&o(b,c));
>       called from line 2, column 19036 in (a) in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js:
>           A.fireWith(c,[e]),e.fn.trigger&&e(c).trigger("ready").off("ready")
>       called from line 2, column 28469 in () in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js:
>           c.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",B,!1),e.ready()

My script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#BuyCredit").button().click(function() {
        $(".buycr").corner();
        $(".buycr").css("display","block");  
      }); 
    });
  </script>
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="buycr" data-corner="15px">
  <div style="width:280px">Text</div>
</div>
<div style="width:100px">
      <span id="HideBox">Zavřít</span>
    </div>
```

Thanks for any feedback

Comment: where is the div with an id of "BuyCredit"? The error is that $('#BuyCredit') returns no items

Answer (score 2):

You're linking to two different versions of jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try getting rid of the latest one (assuming it worked before on 1.7.2).

**[edit]** Since that didn't work, best guess is that whatever `#BuyCredit` was isn't there anymore. That would explain the error `Cannot convert '$("#BuyCredit")' to object`.

Make sure that there is a `#BuyCredit` on your page.

Comment: I tried delete first script, after that second script and change version number to 1.6 and 1.5. But no changes :(